# VB.Net : How to have properties file like java properties file in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I think that we can specify or import our properties that we wish to use in the project in the .vbproj file of our project.

Is that true ?

And.. if so, how will I use these in my VB source code... ?

I want to keep the table names, connection strings, etc in the properties file.

Any help is appreciated !!

Comment: It's unclear why this is tagged `dotnetnuke`, and could you add more description about what properties files provide in java? Have you looked at config files and/or settings, and can you describe how java properties are different?

Comment: Mistake... removed dotnetnuke !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply looking to store strings you can just use the resource file, and retrieve the string with Properties.Resources.Whatever.

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking about the Project Settings files:

You create the settings under the project Properties and them access them as such

```
My.Settings.YourSetting = "thing"
```

Answer (score 1):

This topic is an old one, but may be someone will find this answer useful. When I started to do things with VB.NET I missed java.util.Properties very strongly, so, I made simple class to read the properties file very similar to Java (I am really missing Java :/):

```
Imports System.IO

Namespace Util

    Public Class Properties

        Private m_Properties As New Hashtable

        Public Sub New()

        End Sub

        Private Sub Add(ByVal key As String, ByVal value As String)
            m_Properties.Add(key, value)
        End Sub

        Public Sub Load(ByRef sr As StreamReader)

            Dim line As String
            Dim key As String
            Dim value As String

            Do While sr.Peek <> -1
                line = sr.ReadLine
                If line = Nothing OrElse line.Length = 0 OrElse line.StartsWith("#") Then
                    Continue Do
                End If

                key = line.Split("=")(0)
                value = line.Split("=")(1)

                Add(key, value)

            Loop

        End Sub

        Public Function GetProperty(ByVal key As String)

            Return m_Properties.Item(key)

        End Function

        Public Function GetProperty(ByVal key As String, ByVal defValue As String) As String

            Dim value As String = GetProperty(key)
            If value = Nothing Then
                value = defValue
            End If

            Return value

        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

It can be used the same way as `java.util.Properties`:

```
Imports Util
'some code
Public Shared Sub GetProps(ByVal f As String)
    Dim props As New Properties()
    Dim sr As New StreamReader(projFile)
    props.Load(sr)
    Dim someProp As String = props.GetProperty("propName")
    Dim someProp2 As String = props.GetProperty("propName2", "defaultPropValue")
    sr.Close()
End Sub
' some code
```